# Make the on-topic section more explicit

Tags: discussion, status-completed, help-center

Since there is often confusion on this site as to which Ubuntu derivatives are actually on topic, why not explicitly list them on the Help page? Instead of:

> We welcome questions about:
>
> Using and administering Ubuntu, including [official Ubuntu derivatives](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives).

Something like:

> We welcome questions about:
>
> Using and administering Ubuntu, including [official Ubuntu flavors](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives):
>
> - Edubuntu
> - Ubuntu GNOME
> - Kubuntu
> - Ubuntu Kylin
> - Lubuntu
> - Mythbuntu
> - Ubuntu Studio
> - Xubuntu
> - Ubuntu Touch

My understanding of the scope of AU is that anything not in that list is off topic. Since that is only 8 items that don't change very often, it shouldn't be too hard to maintain (he said, safe in the knowledge that maintaining it is not his job anyway).

<sub>**Note:** This question was modified following the suggestion made in the comments by @Seth and a [discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14180325) we had in chat. See the [edit history](http://meta.askubuntu.com/posts/8682/revisions) for the original version.</sub>

Comment: I'll look at this when I get home.

Comment: Okay, so I'm looking at something [like this](http://i.imgur.com/VorTlQr.png) (leaving the link). What do you think of that? I also like the idea of manually listing them all.

Comment: @Seth I edited the question combining the two: both listing and using _flavors_. What do you think?

Comment: Very good. I'll apply this later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've gone ahead and made the changes. Wanna [double check and make sure I didn't miss anything?](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. One minor nit, perhaps a `<br>` between the first sub-element (Edubuntu) and the flavors line?

Comment: Hm yes, the preview shows a break there, but the rendered page doesn't have one. Odd. Fixed now.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed a [similar bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223002/203101). Apparently it boils down to server-side vs client-side markdown rendering since the preview is rendered on the client while the final is rendered on the server. Thanks again!