# Remove the link to the video tutorials from the help pages

Tags: feature-request, help-center

Due recent [changes to our help page](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8682/169736) I took a peek what was written there too. I found there was a link to some video tutorials, I checked out that was linked to meta.AU, and was in the disposition of watching some just to find they has been deleted of blip.tv.

This produces some frustration of users and a broken feedback loop, since newbies will not have the reputation to comment/answer/get attention. I left a comment to Jorge that the links are dead but meanwhile we should remove the link to prevent frustrations.

> [image]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgvXaCY9uek and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptnlogCqOes - sorry I haven't had time to update them.

Comment: Which help pages link to the video tutorials?

Comment: @Seth there....

Comment: I'm thinking about something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/qumZTqd.png) for now...