# Is Edubuntu 14.04 supported by askubuntu.com?

Tags: discussion

https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic stated in part when I wrote this question:

> Questions that you may ask:
>
> Using and administering official Ubuntu flavors including: Edubuntu (14.04), Ubuntu GNOME, Kubuntu, Ubuntu Kylin, Lubuntu, Mythbuntu (16.04), Ubuntu Studio, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Ubuntu Touch, Ubuntu Budgie (17.04+) and Ubuntu "Snappy" Core.

A [question arose about Edubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165734/link-for-download-latest-edubuntu/1165737) yesterday. After noting the OP could install Ubuntu then add *edubuntu-desktop*, the thought came to me; why do we explicitly specify Edubuntu 14.04 is supported? Why not instead state we support the packages of *edubuntu-desktop* instead, to eliminate the appearance of supporting 14.04?

Inquiring minds want to know :).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The idea is that we only support *official* Ubuntu flavors and those are basically defined as the flavors listed on https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours. That page currently shows:

- Kubuntu
- Lubuntu
- Ubuntu Budgie
- Ubuntu Kylin
- Ubuntu MATE
- Ubuntu Studio
- Xubuntu

That list doesn't include Edubuntu which means we don't support it. Back when this was originally raised, that one specific version of Edubuntu was an official flavor, but since 14.04 has reached EOL it is no longer supported.

However, given that the list now is what I mentioned above, and Edubuntu and Ubuntu Gnome [are marked as deprecated](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors), I edited the on topic page to only mention those:

> Using and administering [official Ubuntu flavors](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives): Ubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, Ubuntu MATE, Kubuntu, Ubuntu Kylin, Lubuntu, Ubuntu Studio and Xubuntu.

If anyone disagrees, now's the time to say so!

---

<sub>The text was changed a while back in response to [a meta question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8682/85695) I had asked when I first started hanging out here on AU. The beautiful irony is that when I asked it I wasn't a mod, so I even included the following:</sub>

> <sub>Since that is only 8 items that don't change very often, it shouldn't be too hard to maintain (he said, safe in the knowledge that maintaining it is not his job anyway).</sub>

<sub>Well, since then things have changed and now it *is* my job to maintain it. D'oh!</sub>

Comment: Secondly, Edubuntu **has not been an official flavor** since 14.04, and 14.04 recently went End of Life, which means our EOL Flavors policy comes into play.  Which is missing in your answer here.

Comment: @ThomasWard ah, that's what I was guessing, good to know I was right.

Comment: Excellent! I am pleased as punch to see this contradiction resolved.

Comment: @K7AAY could you accept this, just so everything is nice and tidy?

Comment: Tidyfication performed.