# Regolith Support

Tags: support

Is Regolith supported on AskUbuntu? I have seen questions about them that haven't been closed on AskUbuntu, but I can't find out whether the ISO is supported. The ISO is not on the official flavors wiki page, so is the regolith package/DE supported but the installer isn't?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because the questions haven't been closed doesn't mean they're on topic.  The specific policy is:

**Any non-official variant or flavor of Ubuntu such as Regolith, Mint, PopOS, etc. are considered *offtopic* here on Ask Ubuntu.**

To quote the Help Center (links stripped by me)

> **Questions that you may ask:**
>
> - Using and administering official Ubuntu flavors: Ubuntu, Ubuntu
>   Budgie, Ubuntu MATE, Kubuntu, Ubuntu Kylin, Lubuntu, Ubuntu Studio and
>   Xubuntu.
> - Running third-party applications on Ubuntu.
> - Development on Ubuntu.
> - Services provided by Ubuntu and Canonical.
>
> Any questions not mentioned below or here are great!
>
> **Questions that you should avoid:**
>
> - Linux Mint, Elementary OS, Backtrack, Gnome-Remix (prior to 13.04),
>   budgie-remix (16.04 and 16.10) and other Linux distributions (try our
>   friends at Unix & Linux Stack Exchange).
> - Bug reports
> - Issues with the next version of Ubuntu (Ubuntu+1)
> - Shopping or Hardware Recommendations
> - Support for versions for Ubuntu releases past their Support or "End
>   of Life" (EOL) — unless the question is asking how to upgrade to a
>   supported release.

We could probably expand the first bullet-point of Questions that you should avoid to read as "any non-official flavor or variant of Ubuntu" with a link to the [official list of Ubuntu Flavors that are recognized](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors), however this should already be self-explanatory as "Regolith Linux" markets itself as a different non-Ubuntu name, so like Kali or Mint or PopOS, fit into the "other Linux distributions" category.

If you are asking "How do i install the Regolith desktop into my Ubuntu 20.04" system, that *could* be ontopic, but there's still a chance you'll not be able to get much support since it was designed for Regolith Linux, not Ubuntu itself.

Comment: I probably shouldn't have used the "Linux" term. Regolith does not advertise itself as "Linux," nore a distro, just a DE. Regolith can be installed as an ubuntu package, so does that mean non-preinstalled DE's are not supported?

Comment: @SealsRock12 see my revision and the last paragraph.  There's nothing stopping you asking how to install a non-official DE but there's no chance you'll get actual support for it if nobody knows how to install it.  Doesn't mean it's offtopic, but doesn't mean you will get support.

Comment: Even though no one will know about it, would questions about things not related to Regolith specifically instead that applies on Ubuntu like a command be on-topic?

Comment: @SealsRock12 the litmus test is if you installed an Ubuntu flavor, then anything you do, including installing non-official packages, changing kernels or anything else is on topic because you are working on an _Ubuntu_ system. If you did not start off by installing an official Ubuntu, then anything you do is off topic here. However, you can always ask on our sister sites [linux.se] for any *nix flavor and [su] for any OS at all.

Comment: @ThomasWard we do link to the official flavors in the first bullet point of "Questions that you may ask". I [bugged Seth](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8682/85695) into doing that back when I first joined AU! :)

Comment: @terdon right, but i meant adjust the wording slightly, because it doesn't say ANYTHING about "non-official variants' officially in the topic ;)